# Client registered with AWS private IP in EUREKA

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka

I'm using an eureka server and different client APIs which are registering with eureka. All the client APIs are in the ec2 instances. My problem is all the client services are registered with their ec2 private IP. Below mentioned the sample client API that register in eureka.

```
Application     AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
USER-SERVICE    n/a(1)  (1)                 UP (1) - ip-10-0-2-178.ec2.internal:user-service:8080
```

How can I register my client APIs with their public IP.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following property,

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    ip-address: <your ip address>
```